# issues with geometry triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

$4$ line drawn parallel to base of triangle such that they are equidistant.if the area of the most bottom part is 4 sq cm. find area of triangle?

**MY THOUGHTS :**

being weak in geometry i couldn't make a single step forward.i am giving what i could analyzed after drawing the diagram

[image]

with out these two analysis i couldnt make a single step forward though i gave a lot time behind it

please help.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The area of the entire triangle is the area of the second largest triangle plus $4$ on the bottom. Since the lines are parallel all the triangles are similar to each other,  all the heights and bases are similar to each other. If we call the area of the entire triangle $a$, the area of the second largest triangle is $\frac{4}{5}  \cdot \frac{4}{5}a$, since the base and height are both $\frac{4}{5}$ of the entire triangle.

$a - \frac{16a}{25} = 4$

Comment: how we are getting 4/5 ???

Comment: @RitabrataGautam All the triangles are similar. The 4 lines drawn are equidistant, let's call their distance $h$. It's easy to see the height of the second largest triangle is $4h$ while the height of the entire triangle is $5h$. Since they're similar the same applies for the bases.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The area of the large triangle is equal to the sum of area of the triangle you get by removing the bottom trapezium and the area of the bottom trapezium.

Hint: The height and base of the smaller triangle which you get by removing the bottom trapezium is exactly four fifths the height and base of the full triangle (show this).

Comment: thanks..voted up..will wait for other answer ..if it still be the best answer will mark as correct

Comment: using `base*height=4` i cant get value of neither base nor height???how can i get the value of height of large triangle and base of small triangle

Comment: There are a few ways you can now take my hint. Here's one. Using the formula that the area of a trapezium is $\frac{1}{2}h(b_1+b_2)$ where $h$ is the height of the trapezium, $b_1$ is the length of the base of the trapezium and $b_2$ is the length of the top edge of the trapezium, you should get the relationship $4=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{5}h)(b+\frac{4}{5}b)$ where here $h$ is the height of the large triangle and $b$ is the base of the large triangle. You should now take this relationship and plug it into the usual formula for the area of the large triangle with this base and height.

Comment: If the area of the full triangle is $A$, you can scale vertically and horizontally by $\frac45$ to get the next largest triangle, which by similarity would then have area $(\frac45)^2 A$. We are told $A-(\frac45)^2 A=4$, so $A=100/9$. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Such triangles can be broken up into equal pieces. Counting those pieces will tell you what the areas you need are.

[image]

If the bottom part has an area of $4$, then $7A=4$. So $A = \dfrac 47$

So the area of the triangle is $16A = \dfrac{64}{7} = 9\frac 17$